# How can I create a subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com

Tags: subdomain, plesk, multiple-domains, domainservices

I want to create something like console.firebase.google.com, I am currently using Plesk Web Admin Panel, and I want to create a subdomain for the subdomain which will be example.example.example.com

How is that possible
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create the main domain `example.com` and create the subdomain `example.example.example.com` by adding `example.example`.
  Or:
- Create the main domain `example.example.com` and create the subdomain `example.example.example.com` by adding `example`.
  Or:
- Create the main domain `example.example.example.com`.

As per Plesk logic, it is possible to create "subdomain" object only for the "main domain". There cannot be "subdomain" of "subdomain".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Just wanted to comment, all 3 works perfectly, but what I would advise is the first one because you can control the DNS easier!